# Qt QGraphicsView translate BackgroundBrush

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have created a view class derived from QGraphicsView and set the backgroundBrush as an image. I want to translate the backgroundBrush. I have tried the following

```
// graphicsView derived from QGraphicsView 
graphicsView->backgroundBrush().transform().translate(moveX, moveY);
```

But it is not transforming the background brush.

Answer (score 1):

`backgroundBrush()` and `transform()` are defined as `const` member functions, meaning they don't modify the object on which they are called.

You need to call `setBackgroundBrush()` and `setTransform()` to modify these properties:

```
QBrush brush = graphicsView->backgroundBrush();
brush.setTransform(QTransform::fromTranslate(moveX, moveY));
graphicsView->setBackgroundBrush(brush);
```